# How to accept an invitation automatically to a GitHub repository?

Tags: github, repository, github-actions, github-codeowners

Monthly I receive several invitations to be a collaborator of several Github repositories, unfortunately sometimes I miss the 7 days time to accept the invitations and as a consequence the invitations expire, making it impossible for me to access the repositories

I have tried to automate the invitations through GitHubActions but there is no such option.

Please, does anyone know how I can automate the acceptance of the invitations, so they will not expire after 7 days, which is the maximum time that Github grants before the invitations expire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have tried to automate the invitations through GitHubActions but there is no such option.

You can test out the GitHub Action [`kbrashears5/github-action-auto-accept-collabs`](https://github.com/kbrashears5/github-action-auto-accept-collabs) which should auto accept all collaboration invites.

It does:

- get all repository invites for [${USERNAME}]

  ```bash
  curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -u ${USERNAME}:${GITHUB_TOKEN} \
       --silent ${GITHUB_API_URL}/user/repository_invitations | \
  jq '.[].id'
  ```
- Accept each invite:

  ```bash
  curl -d @- \
        -X PATCH \
        -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
        -u ${USERNAME}:${GITHUB_TOKEN} \
        --silent \
        ${GITHUB_API_URL}/user/repository_invitations/${invite}
  ```